# How can I get express static to work when starting from another folder

Tags: express

I have the following structure

```
-project
   -packages
       -express-project
           -static
           -dist
              -index.js
```

When I run from express-project everything works fine. However, when I run from project like this `node packages\express-project\dist\index.js` it doesn't map the static folder properly so I get 404s for the resources. My static is set like this `this.express.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "static")));`

How can I start it from another folder?

**Update**

```
import path from "path";
const __dirname = path.resolve();
```

Comment: You will have to show us more code.  `__dirname` should be the directory of the module that your code lives in.  That should not matter how you started node.js.  The current directory will matter how you started node.js.

Comment: I will add the dir name declaration. I don't want to be explicit because I want to be able to run it both places [express-project, project].

Comment: Why are you not using the pre-defined [`__dirname` for your module](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_dirname).  That will reliably always get you the directory of your module which will give you a fixed point in your file system that you can go up or down from regardless of how the program was started.

Answer (score 0):

So this worked...

In my package.json I made my start `"start": "cd .\\packages\\express-project && node dist\\index.js"`. Then I can run `npm start` and it works just as I would expect and after it is done it is still in project.